# Obtener Formato WKT (punto ) A partir de coordenadas x e y

Tags: python

Soy novata en el mundo de python, espero puedan ayudarme.
Estoy intentando obtener formato wkt a partir de coordenadas x e y calculadas desde un GIS. Necesito las coordenadas de inicio y fin en este formato para luego poder obtener un LINESTRIG a partir de ellos. No logro convertir estos x e y obtenidos.
Utilice la Formula  "geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt()" como muestra la ayuda de geopandas.
Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: En la imagen puede verse las columnas x1,y1,x2,y2 que son las coordenadas de inicio y fin de las rectas que busco convertir a LINESTRING]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir tu problema, como texto, no como imagen, así como un ejemplo del resultado deseado.